# How do you style a Custom Element like a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm looking for a consistent cross-browser solution to style custom elements like a DIV. (Ie: resetting to DIV styling as a starting point). Chrome seems to treat custom elements like a `span`.

Here's what I use custom elements for:

- For a `Restrict: E` angular directive.
- As part of a directive's template so I can select a child element using `element.find('custom-element')` from the directive's link or controller function. This is occasionally necessary when building a directive that requires calculating child element dimensions and/or position.

Is it as simple as [doing this](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview):

```
custom-element {
  display: block;
}
```

Or are there gotchas that I should be aware when dealing with certain browsers?

Comment: You can't just target a class? `<div class="custom">`  ... `element.find('.custom')`

Comment: @misterManSam, I'm not loading in jQuery so that's not an option... Although I have considered using `element.querySelector('.custom')`...

Comment: HTML5 has added stacks of semantic elements that cover a host of use cases. Don't make your own elements. Not only do you need to manually style them, **but you'll have accessibility problems as screen readers won't understand them.**

Answer (score 2):

Custom tags is strongly discouraged by those who are working on HTML standards. IE8 and lower forms of Internet Explorer do not by default support unknown tags, the solution is to add a script to create the element.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('custom-element');
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML5 specifies that unknown tags are not erroneous for the browser, but they are for code checkers. Browsers should allow them to be styled with CSS just like tags that the browser is familiar with, and by default they are inline elements not blocks.

The purpose of this is not that everybody creates their own set of tags, which will cause confusion, but to allow new tags to be created into the future without breaking older systems.

Violations of HTML5 standards in the way you are implementing are considered will full violations and are used to consider how to improve the standard when things can not be done using the standards.

To accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, using standards, they have added data attribs and custom attribs http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ ...

```
<div customElement="true"></div>

document.querySelectorAll('[customElement]');
```

... which is what the html5 standards people would like you to use.

Note customElement="true" is a commonly used willful violation

Comment: There are some work arounds for IE8, including style: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie. Over the whole I agree, I've never used angular directives as elements.

Comment: I think you mean `data-custom-element="true"`

Comment: Macek, yes but not using data-* is a common willful violation ... as it can be styled will css div[customElement] { ... }

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Wayne. Is there a specific reason you chose `customElement="true"` vs `custom-element="true"` or just `customElement` or `custom-element` ?

Comment: Gil, javascript does not like the - it likes camelCase

Comment: Why would you ("willfully") omit the `data-` prefix?

Comment: @steveax I'm not exactly sure why http://schema.org/docs/gs.html and others decided it was beneficial to not use the data- prefix. I've not discovered an issue in not using it. None the less there are many cases of willfully omiting the data- prefix.

Comment: I willfully omit the `data-` prefix because it's not DRY.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic element is a span. A div is the block version of a span. Span is inline, and div is block. Therefore, you are correct, if you style your custom element to be displayed as a block, it will be like a div.

Without being styled as display: block

```js
window.customElements.define("hello-world", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        let text = this.textContent;
        let marginLeft = { num: 2, unit: "em" };
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(this.getAttribute("nest-element")) - 1; i++) {
            let divEl = document.createElement("div");
            divEl.textContent = text;
            divEl.style.marginLeft = marginLeft.num + marginLeft.unit;
            marginLeft.num += 2;
            this.appendChild(divEl);
        }
        this.style.border = "1px solid #000";
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-world nest-element="7">This is a custom element.</hello-world>
    </body>
</html>
```

With being styled as display: block

```js
window.customElements.define("hello-world", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        let text = this.textContent;
        let marginLeft = { num: 2, unit: "em" };
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(this.getAttribute("nest-element")) - 1; i++) {
            let divEl = document.createElement("div");
            divEl.textContent = text;
            divEl.style.marginLeft = marginLeft.num + marginLeft.unit;
            marginLeft.num += 2;
            this.appendChild(divEl);
        }
        this.style.display = "block";
        this.style.border = "1px solid #000";
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-world nest-element="7">This is a custom element.</hello-world>
    </body>
</html>
```